# losing reference to the socket in socket.io

Tags: javascript, reference, socket.io, typescript

I am having a typescript class on the server that is handling my socket.io communications that looks like below. basically it works, but ofc  the server just saves the latest socket reference. (the person who last connected to the server, because the variable gets overwritten each time someone connects).

```
class ChatService {
    private server;
    private app;
    private io;
    private socket;
    constructor(app, server) {
        this.app = app;
        this.server = server;
        this.io = require('socket.io').listen(this.server);
        this.io.set('log level', 1);
        this.io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
            console.log('a user connected');
            socket.join('test');
            console.log(this.io.sockets.clients('test').length + ' - ' + socket.id);
            this.socket = socket;
            socket.on('message', (data) => this.onMessage());
            socket.on('disconnect', function(){
                console.log('user disconnected');
            });
        });

    }

    public onMessage() {
        this.socket.broadcast.to('test').emit('message', {
            message: 'test message'
        });
    }

}
export = ChatService;
```

Do you have any good practise how I can have the right reference ( so that i can call `socket.broadcast.to('test').emit()` ). Maybe there is a way, that the client send his socket element, so that i have it on the server?

Comment: But the onMessage should be trigger in client side ? Socket.io is useless here if you receive message on server through the onmessage function.

Comment: I guess not, because on the client I am sending a ´socket.emit('message')´ then I am in the onMessage function and want to broadcast this message to all connected users (except the sender). On the client-side then the connected users get a message, where they can display the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
socket.on('message', (data) => this.onMessage());
```

Change it by this :

```
socket.on('message', (data) => this.onMessage(socket,data));
```

Then you have everything you need for broadcast and resend data.

```
public onMessage(socket,data) {
    socket.broadcast.to('test').emit('message', {
        message: 'test message'
    });
}
```